# ZMQ shows slow performance with many connections in the same server

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I’ve been using ZMQ for quite a while now. I created a distributed system in NodeJS where processes sends data in a stream fashion using ZMQ as the connector (with the NodeJS binding for ZMQ). I tried to stress-test the system on a single machine and connected 10 or more processes in a pipeline (1->2->...->10). The processes just echo the messages received; the machine is big (24 cores with hyperthreading running ubuntu), thus I expect it should be able to host AT LEAST as many number of processes.

If I only create the processes without connecting them, they system is responsive. The moment I connect all those processes it gets incredibly slow (in terms of response delay), while the throughput remains constant. This means the data flows as fast as possible through the processes, but the system itself gets super slow and not responsive (I have a command line interface from which I can create more processes and connect them at runtime, but the moment I add more than 8-10 it gets progressively slower to answer the commands). I think this problem is related to the resource consumption of many ZMQ connections (for each process I receive and send data with ZMQ channels). Could it be the case?

Thanks.

EDIT: here is a snapshot of the code I'm using to connect the processes.

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
[...]
var sender = zmq.socket('push');
var receiver = zmq.socket('pull');
[...]
receiver.bindSync("tcp://*:" + port); //port is a variable received when the process starts up, each process has its own port
//.. some callbacks of the receiver to handle data received
//at some point I connect the sender to the host/port received from a RPC message, then I store the sender in an array (each outgoing connection has its own sender of course)
try {
    sender.connect("tcp://" + msg.host + ":" + msg.port, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
}
//when the stream goes by, I use the following to send the message (c is a variable that stores, among all, the socket)
c.sender.send(JSON.stringify(msg))
```

This is what I'm doing.

EDIT 2:
Let me add a little bit of CPU usage data gathered recently to see what's going on. As I said, the processes just do a simple echo, thus when inspecting the CPU usage through `htop` I don't see spikes in the CPU usage, even for long pipelines. The interesting part comes when, with a long pipeline, I try (through RPC) to add a new process. There is a single CPU which jumps at 100% usage and stands still until the process has been created. I use different commands to bind the process to the pipeline (namely bind and unbind procedures). When calling the bind and unbind, I see another CPU going up to 100% until it's done binding (which may take some time as the pipeline grows). I think this is given by the fact that when adding a new process, the CPU where the RPC server is running gets work to do, while when binding, the process performing the echo message which has to be bound with the new process has to deal with the message, thus its usage increases. This leads me to think that the JavaScript scheduler schedules all the messages incoming and outgoing from the ZMQ edges *before* the RPC call, and since this number of messages increase as the pipeline increases, it leads to slow performance of RPC (and the control structure in general).

EDIT3: This is definitely a problem of ZMQ. I tried to run 15-ish processes, binding them, but NOT running any data stream. As I added more (after the binding), even if there was no data stream involved, the RPC calls got slower and slower. ZMQ scaffolding is too heavy?

Comment: Missing important pieces of information, Masiar.Namely the ZeroMQ means of transport `{ipc|pipe|tcp|...}` used. ZeroMQ global + per-thread ZMQ.Context management policy used. ZeroMQ Formal Communication Pattern elements `{ZMQ.PAIR|ZMQ.PUB|ZMQ.SUB|...}` used in your Architecture. None said. No chance to go deeper and help you with your problem. Post trivialised `<code>-block(s)` for the Architecture you aim at, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited the first post with some of the code I'm using. Actually its pretty simple, I just create the push and pull sockets and use them to send and receive. I do not set anything you mentioned.

Comment: Have you looked into what the actual resource usage is per process?  CPU? Memory? Node has a history of memory leaks (that have been improving quickly over the past year, but it's not too far fetched to think maybe you've hit on one, either in node or in the zmq binding).  Try and figure out how resource usage jumps when you start a new process and when you start a new connection.  Might help narrow in on the problem.  Also, your code may be a little *too* simplified, especially if this is a node problem we don't see much of the node stuff going on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've been watching the CPU usage but not in details. I added some info about it and some conclusions I can gather from it.

Answer (score 1):

**Architecture**

As given above, your threads reside in a **single-host** / **single-OS** environment.

Your processing design aims at having about **small tens** of ZMQ-elements communicating an unspecified set of services amongst the relevant processes.

**Solution**

1. ZMQ-Context occupies one thread for smooth centralised orchestration of resources
2. ZMQ-Socket(s) shall rather use more straightforward protocol-less transport (ref.above)
3. ZMQ-PUB/SUB Formal Pattern might be used for a trivial, scaleable, non-RealTime, central logging / diagnostics of per-process / per-element delays in transaction processing ( that will help you diagnose and stress test the system, as you have designed the message-flow logic. Sub-millisecond pseudo-TimeStamping, process UUIDs & al are up to your level of detail you need to go into )

**Where to start**

as your update above has stated "***I do not set anything ...***"
there seems to be a vast space for misunderstandings, if not misconcepts

Thus a best next step one may do is IMHO to
get a bit more global view,
which may sound complicated for the first few things one tries to code with ZeroMQ, but if you at least jump to the **page 265** of the [**Code Connected, Volume 1 ( ... download-able .asPdf() )**](http://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main%3Afiles/cc1pe.pdf), if it were not the case of reading step-by-step there

**The fastest-ever learning-curve** would be to have first an un-exposed view on the **Fig.60** *Republishing Updates* and **Fig.62** *HA Clone Server pair* for a possible High-availability approach and then go back to the *roots*, *elements* and *details*.

Comment: +1 for detailed answer and links to help. The fact is that I know what's going on in my system, I think figure 60 explains well the usage of `PUSH` and `PULL` I'm doing. The fact is that this still does not explain me why, when connecting the processes, the RPC calls become progressively slower. This makes me think there is a problem with the JavaScript scheduler which doesn't prioritise RPC calls and puts the call under all the scheduling related to the messages circulating through ZMQ. I updated the main post with data about the CPU usage in the system.